# Trouble when importing animation character from mixamo to Reality Composer ( conversion from .FBX to USDZ)

Tags: swift, xcode, mixamo, reality-composer

i've got some trouble when converting and importing mixamo(.FBX) to reality composer (USDZ). The head of my character isn't on his shoulder when importing on reality composer.

NB: i use scapic converter to convert from (.FBX) to (USDZ)

Thanks in advance.

[image: image composer]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Mixamo animated fbx -> usdz Workflow:**

Mixamo -> fbx download

fbx import in Cheetah3D

in Takes tab, make sure "mixamo. com" take is selected

Delete other takes!

Export fbx

In Terminal usdzconvert (from Apple), fbx to usdz

Now works in Xcode, Reality Composer with animation and textures intact

Answer (score 0):

Do all the adjustments and coloring in Blender.  Upload to Mixamo.  Get animation in FBX.  Immediately transfer to apple converter.  From apple converter import to composer.  Animation will work that way.